# Camera Calibration - How To Find The Projection Matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, computer-vision, camera-calibration, projection-matrix

There are many questions that explain how to find the projection matrix but they don't apply to my situation. The Matlab function `cameraMatrix(cameraParams,rotMatrix,tranVector)` can easily find the projection matrix.

I obtained my cameraParams variable by using the camera calibrator app in Matlab by providing checkerboard images in the input. The problem is that in my `cameraParams` variable, there are 10 rotation matrices and 10 translation vectors for some reason. The app always returns 10 rotation and translation vectors no matter what. The function `cameraMatrix()` can only accept a single rotation matrix and translation vector as inputs.

Why are there multiple rotation matrices and translation vectors and how do I find the projection matrix?

Comment: Well, which projection matrix do you consider to be **the** projection matrix? You can make a 100 projection matrices with 10 rotation matrices and 10 translation vectors...

Comment: I obtained my `cameraParams` variable by using the camera calibrator app in Matlab by providing checkerboard images in the input. The app always returns 10 rotation and translation vectors no matter what. So, I don't know which projection matrix I would consider to be THE projection matrix.

Comment: Can you not reduce it to a single rotation matrix and translation vector by properly adding and multiplying them together?

Comment: I'm not sure if that would be a valid thing to do. How would I combine it into a single matrix and vector?